Migrating WordPress site from subdomain to subdirectory
I want to migrate from https://blog.salamzaban.com to https://salamzaban.com/blog
How can I do it?
Thanks

you can use Hosting Backup feature or you can also use Plugin like updraftplus to Migrating WordPress site from subdomain to subdirectory

A quick solution is using Cloudflare Workers to load the blog from subdomain to subdirectory.
You can do it yourself if you have some experience (follow https://shapo.io/blog/wordpress-blog-on-a-subdirectory-with-cloudflare/) or you can use a paid proxy service such as https://pressproxy.io.
